# Unlocker tool (website dead?)

Tags: file-management

I have used and loved Unlocker in the past.  (Helps delete files that are in use by running programs.)

The site that hosted it was http://ccollomb.free.fr/

It seems to be dead now.  Anyone know a reputable source where I can get this tool now?

Comment: just to let you know that the site is back online and the author apologized for the downtime, and set up a mirror: http://cedrick.collomb.perso.sfr.fr/unlocker/

Comment: Both links with "collomb" in the name are dead/outdated now; the site is currently (Aug 2011) at [emptyloop.com/unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) and [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) have the latest version.

You may also be interested in [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/), another freeware tool which works similarly:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The new website is here http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Ignore poor software like lockhunter and fileassassin, just use Unlocker.

Comment: @Tom interesting the [new new Unlocker website](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) now has a comparison table.

Comment: @Steve: That table lost me at the SysInternals Tools, which can do all of the features and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to what John T said

Also, if you're just having trouble with deleting **individual files**, [Malwarebytes' FileASSASSIN](http://www.malwarebytes.org/fileassassin.php) is the most reliable software IMO.